# Where does the idiom "Allô la Terre" come from?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

I’ve heard this idiom, or its variant "Allô la Terre ici la Lune" quite a few times. [It generally serves as a call to get someone’s attention.](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/allo-la-lune-ici.1959522/) Regardless of its meaning, it seems to be fairly popular and is used as [the title of many songs, movies, as well as articles](https://www.philomag.com/articles/allo-la-terre).

I cannot find any "official" definition of this idiom though. Does it have one, and if so, what is its origin? As far as I know, none of the Apollo astronauts ever uttered this sentence.

Comment: @None I didn’t know it existed in English too, which is not my native language, which means I can’t comment on its frequency. I’d like to know if one movie in particular (or something else) popularised the phrase, unless of course the idiom was popularised by several movies (or other sources) overtime.

Comment: @None Or rather, the French equivalent of “Earth to…” is *Allô la **lune**, ici la terre*, since it’s the Earth that’s calling.

Comment: @None I was responding to your first comment. It’s not *Allô la terre, ici…* but *Allô la lune, ici…* that corresponds to “Earth to…”.

Comment: @Segorian Indeed, and as you know, it can be any celestial body, not just the moon! "Hello? Earth to Jupiter!" And it carries more a sense of "Come back down to Earth" — be reasonable or pay attention to something right in front of your nose. "I'm talking to you! Why are you floating off in space?"

Comment: Isn't the original the other way round? "Allo la lune, ici la Terre". Tu es "dans la lune", tu ne fais pas attention, tu penses a autre chose. J'ai "les pieds fermement sur Terre" et j'ai quelque chose a te dire.

Comment: @Carl Not sure. "Allô la Terre" seems way more popular. I cannot get stats on its usage but Google returns about 4 times as many results than for "Allo la lune".

Comment: @Carl No, *allô la Terre, ici la Lune* has nothing to do with the idiom *être dans la lune*. On the opposite, the person calling is alert and try to capture the attention of someone on Earth. If someone is *dans la lune*, that might be the latter but not the remote guy.

Comment: @Mat My comment is based on memories from school and I may be misremembering what teachers used to say to us when we weren't paying attention. Purely anecdotal but at least I'm not alone in having heard it that way round. It wouldn't be the first time that an expression has been corrupted from it's original. The question is which one is the original and I can't help you there.

Comment: @jlliagre Indeed. That's why I'm questioning the premise of the question and suggesting that the original expression and the more common one might be the reverse of what OP has quoted. I only have personal experience (and Occam's razor?) to back this up hence a simple comment.

Comment: @Carl Okay, I understand better now. Teachers might indeed say *Allô !* to a  daydreaming student, possibly even *Allô ! la Terre* but they are unlikely to add *ici la Lune* in that case. What's matter is *Allô !* here, not the celestial bodies despite the students being *dans la lune*.

Answer (score 6):

Its origin might be Tintin's ***On a marché sur la Lune***, published in 1953, where similar sentences can be found:

[image]

Note that ***Allô la Terre, ici la Lune*** has nothing to do with the idiom ***être dans la lune***. On the opposite, the person calling is alert and try to capture the attention of someone on Earth. If someone is ***dans la lune***, that might be the latter but not the remote guy.

Comment: Seems like a very good candidate, considering the popularity and publishing date of this comic book.

Answer (score 1):

A similar saying is present in Portuguese. When we say someone is daydreaming we say they are "living in the world of the Moon" which I believe refers more to the general idea of having one's head far away than to a specific source.

"Allo, allo" just refers to how we pick up the phone or radio and, AFAIK goes back to latin "ave" (hail).

We can probably establish that the expression originated between the end of the XIX century and beginning of XX century. While I highly doubt the expression originated in *On a marché sur la lune*, I do believe it might have been, perhaps unintentionally, one of the first print examples of such an expression in French.

Comment: An almost perfect equivalent exists in French too ("être dans la Lune"). Close, but still different from "Allô la Terre". I’m also not sure phones and the "allô" word were widespread enough for it to enter common language so early.

Comment: What is the Portuguese idiom?